# How do i resolve this MS Access Dcount error?

Tags: ms-access-2016, dcount

Getting the following error....
<The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: 'rs!StoreID'>

rs!StoreID is an integer in the Stores table and prints out just fine in the msgbox function
What am I doing wrong? I've used Dcount many times before, just not in a loop through the records in a table...

Thanks!

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Stores"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    While (Not rs.EOF)
    
        MsgBox ("Store: " & rs!StoreID & ", Name: " & rs!FullStoreName)
        'Make sure data exists for Store in AccountBalances Table for start and end dates
        If ((DCount("*", "AccountBalances", "[RecDate] = TempVars!varDate And [StoreID] = rs!StoreID") <= 0) Or _
        (DCount("*", "AccountBalances", "[RecDate] = TempVars!varStartDate And [StoreID] = rs!StoreID") <= 0)) Then
            NoData = NoData + 1
            NoDataStoreList = NoDataStoreList & rs!FullStoreName & vbCrLf
        End If

        MsgBox ("Checking for CFS Orphans")
        'Check if any Account Numbers for selected Store have Unassigned CFS Line Item in the AccountNumbers Table
        NumRecs = DCount("*", "AccountNumbers", "[StoreID] = rs!StoreID And [CFS LineItem] = 0 And [Account Type] = '2-Assets'") _
            + DCount("*", "AccountNumbers", "[StoreID] = rs!StoreID And [CFS LineItem] = 0 And [Account Type] = '3-Liability'") _
            + DCount("*", "AccountNumbers", "[StoreID] = rs!StoreID And [CFS LineItem] = 0 And [Account Type] = '4-Net Worth'")
        If (NumRecs > 0) Then
            CFSOrphans = CFSOrphans + 1
            CFSOrphansStoreList = CFSOrphansStoreList & rs!FullStoreName & " - " & NumRecs & " Accounts" & vbCrLf
        End If

        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

The values must be concatenated, for example:

```vb
If ((DCount("*", "AccountBalances", "[RecDate] = TempVars!varDate And [StoreID] = " & rs!StoreID & "") <= 0) Or _
(DCount("*", "AccountBalances", "[RecDate] = TempVars!varStartDate And [StoreID] = " & rs!StoreID & "") <= 0)) Then
```

Comment: First - thanks for the response!   When I tried this I get a different error "Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression" - I also got this error when I tried simply enclosed rs!StoreID with single quotes like 'rs!StoreID'        On Data Types - the Store table I am looping through uses StoreID as an auto-generated index.  The 'Account Balances' table I am searching has a field StoreID which is a Number format.

Comment: When I plug a constant in it works..."[RecDate] = TempVars!varDate And [StoreID] = 1"

Comment: OK when I "force" a TempVar to an Int using Cint() it works - forcing a local variable to an Int did not work.  Its working but I really don't understand why - I hate that!    TempVars!varStoreID = CInt(rs!StoreID)
    If ((DCount("*", "AccountBalances", "[RecDate] = TempVars!varDate And [StoreID] = TempVars!varStoreID") = 0) Or _
    (DCount("*", "AccountBalances", "[RecDate] = TempVars!varDate And [StoreID] = TempVars!varStoreID") = 0)) Then
        NoData = NoData + 1
        NoDataStoreList = NoDataStoreList & rs!FullStoreName & vbCrLf
    End If

Comment: OK. Then, of you feel so, please mark as answered.

Comment: So I found a way to work around the issue but I still don't understand why I can't use the rs!StoreID in the DCount function ??                    "[RecDate] = TempVars!varDate And [StoreID] = " & rs!StoreID & ""

Comment: Can't tell. You must debug your data.